# Buscar un valor en una columna de un grupo de tablas

Tags: sql-server

tengo un grupo de tablas que contienen una columna llamada 'UsuarioEditandoId', la idea es que el usuario entra en modo edicion para ese elemento, y no puede editar dos elementos a la vez.
Entonces antes de darle el derecho de edicion, necesito buscar en el grupo de tablas que no haya ningun otro elemento con ese Id editando.

Como podria buscar, con una sp, en un conjunto de tablas, el valor (int) en las columnas con el nombre especificado?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es simple. Se llama UNION ALL

Puedes hacer una select en cualquier conjunto, siempre que el valor devuelto por la misma y las columnas sean el mismo número.

```
create table t1 (col1 int, col2 int, usuarioEditando int);
create table t2 (col1 int, col2 int, usuarioEditando int);
create table t3 (col1 int, col2 int, usuarioEditando int);
go
insert into t1 (col1, col2,usuarioEditando)
values (1,0,0);
insert into t2 (col1, col2,usuarioEditando)
values (1,0,0);
insert into t3 (col1, col2,usuarioEditando)
values (1,1,0);
go
Create Procedure dbo.UsuarioEstaEditando
As
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(O.US) FROM (
        SELECT usuarioEditando AS us
            FROM T1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT usuarioEditando
            FROM t2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT usuarioEditando
            FROM T3
        ) AS O
END
GO
```

Luego la llamada al sp

EXEC dbo.UsuarioEstaEditando

Que en el caso del ejemplo te retorna un 0

[Union All](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/07/union-vs-union-all/)

[Tabla derivada](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/06/tabla-derivada/)